# Multi-dimensional Array Calculation

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

This is the `Array` that I want to display in the `HTML table`.

```
$itemss =array(
array( "name"=>"Blue Pen", "Description"=>"Atlas", "UnitPrice"=>13.50, " AvailableStock "=>200),
array( "name"=>"80 P-Book", "Description"=>"Atlas", "UnitPrice"=>65," AvailableStock "=>100),
array( "name"=>"A4 Paper 500", "Description"=>"Atlas",  "UnitPrice"=>500," AvailableStock "=>20),
array( "name"=>"Red Pen", "Description"=>"Atlas", "UnitPrice"=>13.50," AvailableStock "=>256),
array( "name"=>"Back Pen", "Description"=>"Atlas",  "UnitPrice"=>13.50," AvailableStock "=>156) );
```

The output should be like this in a table.

```
Item Name    |Description|Unit Price|Available Stock|Stock Value

Blue Pen         Atlas      13.50       200           xxxx


Total Stock Value                                   |xxxxxx
```

And this what I have done up to now:

```
<?php
$itemss =array(
array( "name"=>"Blue Pen", "Description"=>"Atlas","UnitPrice"=>13.50,"AvailableStock"=>200),
array( "name"=>"80 P-Book", "Description"=>"Atlas", "UnitPrice"=>65," AvailableStock"=>100),
array( "name"=>"A4 Paper 500","Description"=>"Atlas","UnitPrice"=>500,"AvailableStock"=>20),
array( "name"=>"Red Pen", "Description"=>"Atlas", "UnitPrice"=>13.50,"AvailableStock"=>256),
array( "name"=>"Back Pen", "Description"=>"Atlas", "UnitPrice"=>13.50,"AvailableStock"=>156) );


?>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Available Stock</th>
<th>Stock Value</th>


</tr>
<?php
foreach($itemss as $Rockband)
{
echo '<tr>';
foreach(array_values($Rockband) as $key => $item)
{
echo "<td>$item</td>";

}
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no `Stock Value` in your array, your sub-arrays only contain 4 elements.

Comment: Stock Value = Unit Price * Available Stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Item Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Available Stock</th>
<th>Stock Value</th>


</tr>
<?php
$TotalStockValue = 0;

foreach($itemss as $Rockband)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $Rockband as $key => $value )
    {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    $StockValue = ( $Rockband["UnitPrice"] * $Rockband["AvailableStock"] );
    echo '<td>' . $StockValue . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $TotalStockValue += $StockValue;
}
echo '<tr><td colspan="4">Total Stock Value</td><td>' . $TotalStockValue . '</td></tr>';
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Stock Value = Unit Price * Available Stock

Comment: @user3312802 you're welcomed, please note in your array at first and end of `AvailableStock` index have space, you must deleted spaces

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use foreach on the array like this, using the `list` function

```
$total_stock_value = 0;

foreach($itemss as $one_item) {
    // map the array values to the variables
    list($name, $desc, $price, $stock) = $one_item; 
    $stock_val = $price * $stock;
    $total_stock_value += $stock_val;

    echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td><td>' . $desc . '</td><td>...</td></tr>';
}
```

This should print out a body for a table like you described. You have an array of arrays. So the code above goes through every item of `$itemss` to read the individual arrays into `$one_item` one by one and for each of them it lists (or maps, if you like) the values of that sub-arrray `$one_item` into the given variables (`$name, $desc, ...)`. Then I simply output the variables in the format you described in the question.

**Edit** I have seen your update about the `Stock Value` and `Total Stock Value` so I edited my answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. However you dont need to use `array_values`.

```
<?php
$totalValue= 0;
foreach($itemss as $Rockband)
{
    $stockValue = $Rockband["UnitPrice"] * $Rockband["AvailableStock"];
    $totalValue += $stockValue;
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $Rockband as $key => $value )
    {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>$stockValue</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo $totalValue;
?>
```